# enviar informações de login ao banco para comparação

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com login e senha, utilizando laravel.
A parte de cadastro foi até fácil:

```
public function salvar(){
    $usu_email = Request()->input('usu_email');
    $usu_senha = Request()->input('usu_senha');
    $usu_tipo = Request()->input('usu_tipo');

    DB::insert('INSERT INTO usr_usuario (usu_email, usu_senha, usu_tipo) VALUES (?, md5(?), ?)', array($usu_email, $usu_senha, $usu_tipo));

    return redirect() ->action('ProjetoController@inicio');
}
```

Porém na parte de enviar as informações ao banco e compará-las estou um pouco confuso. No banco tenho o seguinte script que fará a comparação:

```
 select usu_codigo,usu_tipo 
 from usr_usuario
 where usu_email=:usu_email
 and usu_senha=md5(:usu_senha)
```

Mas não sei como faço no meu ProjetoController.php para enviar as informações. Creio que seja algo parecido com o de enviar para o banco na parte de cadastro.

Comment: Por favor, não use imagens para mostrar o teu código. Coloque ele como texto para podermos ajudar.

Comment: porque você não utiliza os métodos de próprios do laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a autenticação que o próprio **Laravel** já disponibiliza.

No início do seu controller dê um "*use Auth;*" para poder utilizar a classe *Auth* dentro do seu controller.

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if ( Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => bcrypt( $password ) ])) {
        // Autenticação autorizada...
    }
}
```

Comment: então, eu não estou usando o formulário pronto que vem no Laravel e também não estou usando os nomes das tabelas que vem no Laravel, o que preciso mudar e onde?